# Why are new elements appearing by default at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to HTML/CSS, but like to think I have a rather good grasp on most aspects. However, this confuses me.

On my dummy website, no matter what new element I add, it's automatically being placed in a specific position near the top of the page. I've tried fiddling with the CSS but to no avail.  In this example, the `p` element with value "Example element" is the last element in the code but appears just under the `nav` in the code snippet.

You may have to run the snippet fullscreen; I'm not sure as I haven't done any viewport stuff and it's been made to fit my abnormally-wide monitor.

Maybe I haven't been introduced to this particular concept yet.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans Std';
    src: url(GillSansStd.otf) format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SofiaPro';
    src: url(SofiaPro.otf) format("opentype");
}

#logo {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

header > h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: thin;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 90px;
    width: 380px;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 650px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

    nav > a {
        margin-left: 85px;
        margin-right: 85px;
        font-family: "Raleway";
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 10px;
    }

        nav > a:link {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        nav > a:visited {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        nav > a:hover {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

#hero-content {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}


#title {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: SofiaPro, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#subhead {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans Std';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: dimgrey;
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-color: dimgrey;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#hero {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

#heropara {
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-gb">

<head>
    <title>Blah Group</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">BLAH</a>
        <a href="#">BLAH</a>
        <a href="#">BLAH</a>
        <a href="#">BLAH</a>
        <a href="#">BLAH</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="hero-content">

        <h1 id="title">BLAH</h1>
        <h2 id="subhead">BLAH</h2>
        <p id="heropara">Lorem Ipsum blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</p>
    </div>

    <img id="hero" src="https://www.littlethings.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dummy-image-green-e1398449160839.jpg" height="200" width="200" />

  <p>Example element</p>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `float` makes everything harder; use flexbox or grid.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'd definitely like to explore that, but the two books I have on HTML5 + CSS3 were published in 2014 and don't mention it.  Maybe because they weren't in the spec at that time?

Comment: Its because the heroelement doesn't take up all the width, If you want a two column layout, then hero element and the dummy image need to nested inside a div that takes up 100% of the width

Comment: 2014 was a lifetime ago... and I've lived several lifetimes ;). A book published in 2014 was probably written in 2013 from material gathered in 2012. That's why I do all my learning online these days. It is as @Pheonix2105 says, but put more simply, you need to "clear your floats" if you want something to come after them.

Comment: Do take a look at flex-boxes, it does handle this kind of thing for you. Flex boxes while not recent probably weren't anyway near as widespread in 2014 :) things move fast in webdev. Most people used a JS/CSSframework (bootstrap etc)to handle neatly laying out content before CSS 3.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for that :)